# Should I use pretrained word2vec or train word2vec on my own dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, word-embeddings, word2vec

I am trying to perfrom fake news detection using machine learning naive bayes classifier. So far I have used BOW and TFIDF as my feature vectors. From research I have found that word embeddings plays a crucial part in text classification and I want to use word2vec to generate word vectors and then take its average to represent the document.

I am having a great confusion on deciding the best option: either use pretained word2vec model or train word2vec on my own dataset. Which option would be good for my project and also why?

I have a labeled dataset of fake and real news. I have preprocessed the dataset by removing punctuation, by stemming and also its lemmatized. So If I used a pre trained word2vec model, would that be a good option to use in my preprocessed dataset?

I think the dataset used in pretrained model (say google-news dataset word2vec model) is preprocessed in one way and mine is preprocessed in another way so it's not the best idea to use pretrained model.Is that so?

Comment: You should use the method that does the best job for your purpose. Using a pre-trained embedding might not have relevance to your task. Training your own embedding might not have enough data to be useful. There are risks either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever using pre-trained models think about the fact of how the data is differently distributed. If the pre-trained model has a very different distribution of data as compared to your problem then it's highly possible that this pre-trained model won't provide any gain.

If not it can be used in your problem since usually, the pre-trained models have a high-quality dataset with lots of computing power spent on finding the best model.

If they are, you should think if there is a possibility of re-training the model with your dataset by setting a high learning rate for the model when passing your dataset. If you want to avoid such trouble, it would be great to train your own given you have the compute power & data size.